# Problema ao passar valor para variável PHP com Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Eu sei que deve ser um problema frequente e tudo mais, mas eu procurei em diversos lugares e não consegui arrumar o meu problema:

No projeto em que estou trabalhando há uma função em javascript em que uma variável chamada `codigo` recebe um determinado valor.

Então quando um botão é clicado, o valor da variável `codigo` deve ser passado para uma variável em PHP para inserção no banco.

O problema é que eu não consigo fazer essa transferência com os valores.

Aqui está a parte onde está o botão

```
<input  type="submit" name="btnEnviar" onclick="ConfirmarAssinatura();" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Confirmar Assinatura"/>
```

Aqui está a parte em Javascript:

```
    function ConfirmarAssinatura(){


    $.ajax({

      url:'tela-planos.php',
      type:"POST",
      cache: false,
      data: { 'cod': codigo },
      success: function (){
        alert (codigo)
      },
      erro: function(result){
        alert('errou')
      }

    });


  }
```

E aqui está a parte do código php onde efetuará a ação:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['cod'])){

// executa o resto do código.

}
```

O problema é que não está funcionando. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Onde está definido `codigo` no JS? Algum alerta é exibido? Qual? no PHP, qual o retorno de `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: "_O problema é que não está funcionando_"... essa frase é genérica e ampla demais. Diga o que não está funcionando?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a variável `codigo` está definida no começo no script do js. É uma variável global. O Alert aparece no `success`. Isso que eu acho estranho, aparece a mensagem de success mas não cai no if do PHP

Comment: @dvd O comentário acima diz o que está acontecendo

Comment: Quando e como a variável `codigo` é definida?

Answer (score 0):

A variável **codigo** não estava definida. Agora ela está pegando o value do seu input, que no momento é **Confirmar Assinatura**. No seu código PHP você terá algo do tipo:

```
echo $_POST['cod'];
```

Isso vai imprimir na tela **Confirmar Assinatura**

```js
function ConfirmarAssinatura(){
    var codigo = $('#myinput').val();
    console.log(codigo);
    $.ajax({
        url:'tela-planos.php',
        type:"POST",
        cache: false,
        data: { 'cod': codigo },
        success: function (data){
            alert (data)
        },
        erro: function(result){
            alert('errou')
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="submit" name="btnEnviar" onclick="ConfirmarAssinatura();" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Confirmar Assinatura" id="myinput"/>
```

Comment: A variável `codigo` está declarada no começo do código JS. É uma variável global. O Ajax exibe o alert do success, mas o if do PHP não funciona. Isso que está me confundindo.

Comment: Esse if não é necessário. Faça o seguinte, retire todo o código do seu arquivo PHP e apenas faça um print_r($_POST); e olha o que aparece no seu alert. Repare que eu mudei a sua requisição ajax acrescentando a variável de retorno na função de success. Atualize isso no seu código antes de fazer o teste acima.

Comment: Não exibe nada. Exibe a mensagem do success mas não acontece nada, parece que nem está enviando os valores ou chamando a página colocada no `url`

Comment: o arquivo tela-planos.php está no mesmo diretório onde você está chamando esta função?